# Change gradle build directory in android studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and I am just learning to build using Gradle. However, with the default project setup, my builds are located in the project directory and I would like to have them placed elsewhere (preferably outside of the project directory). Is it possible to achieve this? Where do I make a change and what change do I make?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in root `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "/path/to/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

See also [Gradle global build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340946/gradle-global-build-directory)

and docs https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Comment: Works like a charm. Had do shift my build folder out of `eCryptfs` directory!

Comment: Yeeeee! I can finally work in our company's Dropbox, thank you!

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov I tried this and something similar by jsut applying it to subprojects, but, i only get some things move out of the default directory, i still see the R files and the intermediates (like exploded-aar, and things like that) on the default directory, which are the things that i wanted to move out in the first place, any idea what can i do? i've tried everything i've found online as far now

Comment: This will cause: `Duplicate content roots detected` for test directories.

Comment: Had to tell MalwareBytes that gradle was not making a Exploit.PayloadProcessBlock once I did this.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the "buildDir" property to the gradlew.bat (I'd assume you can do this in the Linux version as well but I haven't tested it)

Example:

```
gradlew.bat assembleRelease -PbuildDir="C:\BuildFolder"
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a new app a few days with

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377, built on November 13, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

and the above no longer work. I hate that.

But found that this one does

```
allprojects {
    setBuildDir("C:/Users/YourUserNameHere/AppData/Local/Android/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}")

}
```

I use this when I want to run/compile that/any app while it's in Google's "My Drive" In this way, I can code on multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new app with the nowadays default Kotlin DSL `builDir = "path"` indeed doesn't work. However, `builDir = file("path")` still does, being deprecated nevertheless. While `setBuildDir("path")` is its direct successor, however meanwhile this as well became drepacted as has to replaced by the following.

At least for Kotlin DSL, latter however is now as well deprecated and you should switch towards the following.

```
layout.buildDirectory.set(file("C:/Users/YourUserNameHere/AppData/Local/Android/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"))
```

Despite its name `file()` indeed works for directory paths as well

> Regarding old Groovy Gradle `builDir = "path"` is still the "non-deprecated" way to go.

Answer (score -3):

The project iml file has a BUILD_FOLDER_PATH attribute.  I haven't tried changing it myself yet, so not sure if it will work.   The default value is $MODULE_DIR$/build.

Edit: I did a quick test and this did not work.  Once changed, the project needs to reload because the iml file changed.  Upon reload it reverts the build directory to default.

Comment: I never used this answer. So I can't verify that it is indeed correct.

Comment: Note that this answer is telling you something *_NOT_* to do! That `.iml` is automatically generated.