# Specify .gradle taskArtifacts directory

Tags: android-studio, gradle, path

Using Android Studio:
To keep my source directories small, for google drive backup etc, I found how to specify a global gradle build directory outside my project directories here:
[Gradle global build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340946/gradle-global-build-directory)
Is it possible also to put the rather large .gradle/.../taskArtifacts directory outside the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`--gradle-cache-dir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) when invoking gradle from the command line.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, and I cannot find out how to issue this command to Gradle. Would you know how to do it in a Gradle initialization script?