# how to change the .gradle floder directory where Inside the project folder in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

the similar question [Change gradle build directory in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008485/change-gradle-build-directory-in-android-studio)

I mean not to set the "GRADLE_USER_HOME" to "other directory"

the .gradle floder is Automatically generated in the Android project

show the pic

[.gradle floder img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGfS.png)

thanks!!

Comment: this `.gradle` directory is managed by Gradle and created at the root project level (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root).  you are not supposed to move this directory elsewhere; it will be automatically created again at same location. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I just whant to keep my project clean, without anyother created by gradle......the ```build```directory is also managed by Gradle but it can be moved to another directory ,,Thank you for your time.